Can all loop groups be realized as direct limits of finite dimensional Lie groups?
The loop group $LG$ is the group of smooth maps from the circle to a general compact Lie group $G$. My question is: can $LG$ always be realized as an appropriately defined "limit" of an infinite sequence of compact Lie groups $S_m$? If so, in what categories can this limit be realized as a direct limit?

How do you put a group structure on $LG$?

If we parametrize the circle by a compact coordinate $\theta$, then an element of LG is just a function of the form $e^{if(\theta)}$. Group multiplication corresponds to $(f \cdot g)(\theta) = f(\theta) + g(\theta)$.
